# Unable to use method accessors on attributes in a session using JSTL

Tags: java, jsp, session, jstl, accessor

I have an object of type Employee in a session, called User and it contains the method

```
public String getType() {
    return type;
}
```

I want to use this value on a .jsp page using JSTL and i'm using the code

```
${sessionScope.User.getType eq 'Supervisor'}
```

to access this. But it keeps throwing an exception

```
PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'getType' not found on type model.Employee
```

and I can't figure out why. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$` operator can read any object in the `sessionScope` and also other [implicit object](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_expression_language.htm)

Just type it like that

```
${User.type}
```

So the condition will be like that:

```
${User.type eq 'Supervisor'}
```

Comment: When I do that, it throws `code`PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'type' not readable on type model.Employee. I tried setting the property to public, it still throws the same thing.

Comment: it's defined in the Employee class 
`code` public String employeeID, fName, lName, superiorID, email, department, username,type;

it was private before, and I changed it to public to see if it works then.

Comment: Is your `Employee` class declared as `public`?

Comment: That's it! It was just "class". public works! I copied this class over from another class, while trying to solve the original problem, and would've missed the public.

Answer (score 0):

JSLT EL adheres to the Java Beans specification.

Instead of using the method name use its bean shortname

For you code, it should be written as such:

```
${sessionScope.User.type eq 'Supervisor'}
```

Note 'type' not getType()

Comment: is the bean shortname the same as the variable name? The variable is called type but it throws PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'type' not readable on type model.Employee.

Comment: The var name does not come into play, only the method. If getType() is the method name, you would use type.